# scatter plot of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

I am trying to understand if we can predict, how approximately scatter plot of two independent random variables will look like. If the independent random variables are X and Y, x axis and y axis is for random variables X and Y respectively. I would expect that the scatter plot should be a line parallel to x axis as when X changes Y will not change. Another line parallel to y axis as when Y changes X will have no effect.

If someone could guide me if my interpretation of independence with scatter plot is correct.

Comment: "scatter plot of an independent random variable" should be "scatter plot of an 2 independent random variables"

Comment: What you're saying sounds correct. If the two random variables are independent then the distribution of Y values in your sample for any given X value should be similar (assuming you have a large enough sample). So if you look parallel to the y-axis at different points on the x-axis, the distribution of the Y values should be close. Same thing if you look parallel to the x-axis at different points on the y-axis.

Comment: I advise you a first contact with independance by typing the following program (Matlab syntax): n=1000;plot(random(1,n),random(1,n)); you will fill the square [0,1] x [0,1]. No trend at all...

Comment: @JeanMarie edited, to change from an independent to two independent. Thanks, Will plot and observe.

Comment: @FullofDill thanks for confirming.